# Duplicate Table of figures and table of tables in the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, cross-referencing

[image]In the table of content, many elements are redundant such as list of figures, list of tables, content, and reference.

```
   \documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}
%\input{./prem/packages}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[clean,pdf]{svg}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\usepackage{ltablex}% <-- added
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added

%%------------- REF et sommaire cliquables ------------ 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}   

%%-------------------------------------
%\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\title{Bibliography management: \texttt{natbib} package}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
% \usepackage{tikz}
% \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{pdflscape} %rotation table
%\usepackage{afterpage} %rotation table
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{plate}{htpb}{plt}[chapter]
\floatname{plate}{Plate}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

Comment: you have shown many lines of code here (including spurious lines such as loading graphicx 3!! times) but almost none of it is related to tables of contents, please post an example of the problem that you are seeing, without any packages not related to the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I uploaded a figure by editing the first question.

Comment: that shows the output but you have still posted no code that shows why you got that output. Please edit the code block so that it does not include dozens of unrelated packages such as tikz and colortbl but does produce a table of contents with duplicate wording. What you show is not the standard layout for table of contents so you have some code that is causing that but it is not the code you have shown so far.

Comment: Do you really need package `tocbibind`? It cause your problem.

Comment: I don't know which are the useful packages and the non-useful ones. I'm trying to figure out what are the one related to the table of content

Comment: @Zarko I put in a comment and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Also remove all duplicates in preamble. It is good habit to group packages for the same purposes (for example for tables, toc), `hyperref` should be loaded last in preamble, etc.  As already mentioned @DavidCarlisle.